# Switching on Wi-Fi automatically on startup

Tags: wifi, wicd

I run Debian 10 with Wicd as the network manager. When I start the computer, wicd is running:

```
$ ps aux | grep wicd
root       416  2.5  1.5  36144 15180 ?        Ss   19:11   0:00 /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/wicd-daemon.py --no-daemon --keep-connection
root       524  1.2  1.4  25576 13716 ?        S    19:11   0:00 /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/monitor.py
kalle      830  0.0  0.0  10708   684 pts/0    S+   19:12   0:00 grep wicd
```

However, when I start `wicd-client`, Wi-Fi is not enabled:

[image: Wicd window]

If I click "Switch on Wi-Fi" and then click on "Refresh" I get a list of networks to choose from. How do I switch on Wi-Fi automatically when the computer is started so that Wicd can automatically connect to my default network?

### Update

It turns out that wlan is blocked when the computer has started:

```
$ sudo rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE       SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0      blocked unblocked
 1 wlan hp-wifi unblocked unblocked
 2 wwan hp-wwan unblocked unblocked
```

If I run `sudo rfkill unblock 0`, Wi-Fi is switched on. How do I prevent wlan0 from getting blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this thread:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1324810#p1324810

```
# echo "blacklist hp_wmi" > /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf
```